# How to install Numix theme on KDE

Tags: kde, numix

I'm trying to install Numix theme on KDE. I've seen the tutorials on how to install using numix repo, but it gives the following error:

```
yuri@Yuri-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install numix-kde-theme
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package numix-kde-theme
```

Comment: Soo.. did you add the repo before trying to install it?

Comment: Yes, I did, but I keep getting the same error